# data.table keyby mixing up records

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table keyed by (cust,loc,product).
It has multiple entries for each key combination.
For a simulation of this table can be generated as follows (the original table is much larger but this seems to reproduce the issue):

```
set.seed(1)
IM_Demand_DT <- data.table(cust="11", loc="11", product="P1", tsum=runif(10,0,100), priority=runif(10,0,1))
setDT(IM_Demand_DT, key=c("cust", "loc", "product"))
```

I can return selected rows:

```
IM_Demand_DT[list(loc="11", product="P1"),
    .(cust, loc, product, tsum, priority, .I), on=c("loc","product")]

#    cust loc product     tsum   priority  I
# 1:   11  11      P1 12.97134 0.92240856  1
# 2:   11  11      P1 98.22407 0.53635379  2
# 3:   11  11      P1 82.67184 0.04616465  3
# 4:   11  11      P1 24.23550 0.37018108  4
# 5:   11  11      P1 85.68853 0.66773850  5
# 6:   11  11      P1 84.08788 0.61719564  6
# 7:   11  11      P1 34.21633 0.49358856  7
# 8:   11  11      P1 70.62672 0.79673830  8
# 9:   11  11      P1 62.12432 0.04203652  9
#10:   11  11      P1 65.37663 0.64593408 10
```

I want to return these rows sorted by the priority column

```
IM_Demand_DT[list(loc="11", product="P1"),
    .(cust, loc, product, tsum, priority, .I), on=c("loc","product"), keyby=priority]
#      priority cust loc product     tsum   priority  I
# 1: 0.04203652   11  11      P1 70.62672 0.04203652  8
# 2: 0.04616465   11  11      P1 24.23550 0.04616465  4
# 3: 0.37018108   11  11      P1 34.21633 0.37018108  7
# 4: 0.49358856   11  11      P1 65.37663 0.49358856 10
# 5: 0.53635379   11  11      P1 82.67184 0.53635379  3
# 6: 0.61719564   11  11      P1 84.08788 0.61719564  6
# 7: 0.64593408   11  11      P1 12.97134 0.64593408  1
# 8: 0.66773850   11  11      P1 98.22407 0.66773850  2
# 9: 0.79673830   11  11      P1 85.68853 0.79673830  5
#10: 0.92240856   11  11      P1 62.12432 0.92240856  9
```

The priority column is correctly sorted, but the remaining columns are in random sequence.

For example, the first row, with priority 0.04203652 should have tsum=62.12432 and I=9, but in this 'sorted' output it has tsum=70.62672 and I=8.

Is this a bug, or is there a syntax rule that I am breaking here?

Comment: Not sure the explanation for your result, but I would do the sorting as a separate step: `IM_Demand_DT[list(loc="11", product="P1"), .(cust, loc, product, tsum, priority, .I), on=c("loc","product")][order(priority)]`

Comment: code isn't reproducible

Comment: @Frank thanks for this pointer

Comment: @jangorecki - I have edited the post so that it can be readily reproduced without requiring access to the original table.

Comment: I edited my vote then :)